# How do I convert a wav file to mp3 format using sox?

Tags: mp3, centos, wav, sox

When I run sox directly from the command line as ;

```
sox -r 8000 -c 1 <wavfilename> <mp3filename>
```

I get the following error message:

> sox: Unknown output file format for
>   '747a.mp3':  File type 'mp3' is not
>   known

My machine is running the CentOS operating system.

Comment: So I guess this means that the issue is in no way Perl-related?

Comment: So I also guess that this is not programming related?

Comment: This should be moved to Superuser.

Comment: I have had the same issue in the command line.

Answer (score 12):

As an alternative (if all you need is to encode a Wave file to MP3) you can just use LAME to achieve the same results, for example:

```
lame -b 32 --resample 8 -a <wavefilename> <mp3filename>
```

LAME can be installed on CentOS painlessly using yum. You'll first need the RPMForge repository:

```
rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Then:

```
yum install lame
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to get sox working for forever and a half, but this just worked out of the box with no hassle. Saved me probably hours of trying to figure out why no one else's solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to install an appropriate MP3 encoder, e.g. [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/download.php), or recompile Sox with liblame support.

This is independent of your Perl programming :)

Comment: Guess one needs to figure out how to do that....

Answer (score 5):

For CentOS you will need to recompile SOX (the base repo has the sox srpm) with the libmad and lame-devel libraries installed (rpmforge has those.)  Once that is done, sox -h will list supported formats.  When mp3 libraries are installed,

```
sox -t wav -r 8000 -c 1 <wavfilename> -t mp3 <mp3filename>
```

Comment: Hints for enabling RpmForge (to install libmad-devel and lame-devel): http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge

You'll also need alsa-lib-devel and libvorbis-devel

And some info about SRPM: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM

Comment: Is CentOS always a pain in the rear?

Comment: @SashaYanovets Thanks thanks thanks! that fixed the "Sox was compiled without mp3 encoding support" thank you again